# C programming - Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

Having trouble with some command line argurments, basically just trying to make a rectangle using command line argrumnents.  Here's what I've got

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int x;
    int y;
    int i;
    int j;

    x = atoi(argv[1]);
    y = atoi(argv[2]);

    fprintf(stderr, "Height & Width Needed\n", argv[0]);

    return 1;

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I know this is amateur hour but I'm just starting out. Added stderr for argv[0] statement, included atio, every time compile I just get my usage statement.  I tried adding curly braces on my outer loop only, and then on the outer and inner loop, still just getting my stderr every time I run with commands.

Comment: `int x = argv[1];` --> `x = atoi(argv[1]);` (`#include <stdlib.h>`)

Comment: Command line arguments are strings. They must be converted to `int`s, if an `int` is what's desired. `atoi` is one way. Other options: `strtol` and `sscanf`.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= x; i++)` maybe --> `for(i = 0; i < x; i++){ ... }`

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY, I can't believe I forgot atoi.. so I want to be able to do this without using scanf, when I put that in I'm getting "redeclaration of 'x' with no linkage..

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, my bad forgot to take out the 'int' part.  Still not working, it's got to be my printf statements.

Comment: You don't have enough braces.

Comment: Please stop editing the question.  You are invalidating comments and answers. You are confusing everyone and wasting their time.  SO is not a service for incremental testing and debugging!   Think about future users/visitors trying to make sense of your mutating question:((

Comment: The `return 1;` in the middle of the function will of course return to the operating system, and never execute the second half of the code.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is not like Python, you must put bracket to create block. There is no `if` structure around your `return 1;` so it will be always executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s height width\n", argc > 0 ? argv[0] : "");
        return 1;
    }
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    int y = atoi(argv[2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note: `atoi()` don't detect error, use `strtol()` instead.

Comment: @Stargatuer, thanks for the help, I added this but It still doesn't seem to work.  It just does nothing.  Added the argc != 3 portion as well with an stderr but it still returns nothing when I (example) ./rec 3 9.....nothing, ugh I know it's something small I'm missing

Comment: sorry about that.  Still confused a bit on how to properly comment.  I do appreciate the help.